# Object Geometry Instance does not fully function with scale

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes

I'm following the tutorial on Youtube and I'm currently having a problem. My problem starts at 11:30 of the video which I will leave it below, from Scale -> Apply to Scale when I try to reference the Cylinder as sprinkles of the donut. The reference Cylinder is always smaller than the actual one. The only way for me to increase the size of the Object Geometry is either by increasing the Scale on the Instances on the Points node or increasing the scale of the original Cylinder. What's wrong and how do I fix this?

Image of the error:

[image]

Video tutorial: https://youtu.be/4WAxMI1QJMQ

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you have two possibilities to correct the relations of the scaling.

1. Either you use your object in the `Object Info` node relative to your geometry:

   [image]
2. Or you apply the current scaling of your object so that it can be used with the correct dimensions:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but when I was clicking on the *Scale* option it wasn't changing the size properly, the sprinkles were still too small.

I realized that the scale wasn't set to 1 when I originally created my mesh, in the start of the tutorial video he explains this very quickly.

You need to go to the navigation panel (<kbd>N</kbd> key) and set scale to 1

[image: In the navigation panel, the scale is set to 1]